# Interception of udp-packets on router

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a client on PC. I have a server on PC. The client and server are connected via a router with firmware based on Linux OS. 
The client sends a packet to the server and receive a response. The router must intercept the packets and modify it. Something like sniffing but it's not a sniffing because i need to modify the packets.
I must to write a program for this.
I tried to open a raw socket on the router, but reсvfrom on raw socket does not intercept the packet and just copy it. The packet is going on.
Could you suggest me any way to solve this problem?
P.S. Sorry for my bad English. :)

Comment: I wrote the program for the router. This program opens a raw socket and receives UDP packets. Receiving works normally but the package continues to move to the original receiver.
I need to "snatch out" this packet, modify it and "put back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the module for the kernel and some applications. Module uses netfilter and discards packets that I need to netfilter_queue. The application processes a queue and I decide what to do with each package.

```
uint hook_main(uint hooknum,
                  struct sk_buff *skb,
                  const struct net_device *in,
                  const struct net_device *out,
                  int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)  )
{
     struct iphdr *ip;
     struct udphdr *udp;
     if (skb->protocol == htons(ETH_P_IP)){
        ip = (struct iphdr *)(skb->data);
        if (ip->version == 4 && ip->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP){
            udp = (struct udphdr *)(skb->data + sizeof(struct iphdr));
            if(ntohs(udp->dest) == SOME_PORT){
                return NF_QUEUE;
            }
        }
     }
     return NF_ACCEPT;
}

int init_module ()
{
    printk("[udp-catch] start udp-catch\n");

    catch_hook.hook = hook_main;
    catch_hook.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    catch_hook.pf = PF_INET;
    catch_hook.hooknum = NF_INET_FORWARD;
    catch_hook.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
    nf_register_hook(&catch_hook);

    return 0;
}
```

And [a redesigned sample from netfilter.org](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/nfqnl__test_8c_source.html) is the application.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a mix of `iptables` and `libnetfilter_queue` (assuming your kernel is relatively recent)

1. Add to the `iptables` a rules that forward all the udp packets to the `NFQUEUE 0` in order to get packets from kernel to user space.

   `iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport xxxxx -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0`
2. Build a process who listen to the `NFQUEUE number 0`, modify payload and give the full packet back to the kernel space using `libnetfilter_queue` capabilities. Follow [this link](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html#ga593b576017b7423646f49558a39f4ee5) to know how to do it.

In a nutshell you have to open the queue 0 (`nfq_create_queue`), set the mode in order to get the content of the packet (`nfq_set_mode`), then loop in an infinite `recv` to get ever udp packet filtered by `iptables`

```
fd = nfq_fd(h);

while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) >= 0) {
    printf("pkt received\n");
    nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
}
```

Everytime you call `nfq_handle_packet` is called, the callback defined during the `nfq_create_queue` phase is called. In that callback you have to modify the payload, update the size and recalculate the checksum, then set as "valid" with `nfq_set_verdict`

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Routers will automatically send out whatever they receive on their other ports.

e.g.  For a 4 port router, what comes in on port 1 will be sent out on ports 2,3 & 4.

To do what you require, you need another PC with 2 network cards.  Connect your client PC to one network card, and the server PC to the other.

Then your program will need to *recvfrom* on one network card, modify the packet and *sendto* on the other network card.

Comment: I have two PC and router only. And specific job.

Comment: There might be some way to configure the hardware to not automatically forward packets to the other ports, but to try and do what you're doing in software is not going to have great throughput.

Comment: Do you suggest to configure router that it don't send traffic further?

Comment: If this can help, my program seems like latent proxy server.

Comment: "latent" - or "transparent" maybe. It's more correctly, I think.

Comment: "For a 4 port router, what comes in on port 1 will be sent out on ports 2,3 & 4" - that's how a _hub_ used to work, back in the 1980s. Nowadays, you'd have a _switch_ or a _smart switch_ which forwards what's received on port 1 to _exactly one_ of 2, 3, or 4, depending on the routing table it maintains, or drops the packet, if it matches a filter rule. A router, on the other hand, is normally something you don't have in your network, but between your network and another one (or between two of your networks). Routers are usually _much_ more complex than "forward all that comes in".

Comment: For example, routers will typically implement things like stateful firewalls (i.e. block every incoming traffic, except if outgoing packets to the same address have been seen recently), QoS (i.e. your VoIP phone doesn't disconnect when your roommate downloads a porn movie), and virtual private networks, or NAT.

Comment: @damon All of the things you say are true, but are generally written in firmware/hardware, not software.  If he wants to implement his product in software, then he will have to disable the auto-forwarding part of the chipset.  Software just can't keep up with much beyond 10Mbs let alone 100/1000.

Comment: Hmm, the theoretical maximum possible number of frames per seconds is 1.488 million on a gigabit ethernet. This assumes raw ethernet frames with no data (not even an IP header). Realistically, you can expect something around 100k frames/second top. That's no challenge at all for software (which doesn't do the heavy lifting anyway, just the routing decision). Both my 8-port gigabit switch and my VDSL router run Linux on some low-power ARM chip with 30-40% CPU usage when the cable is _really busy_.